# How to pass all the rows from table to blade view?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

Controller:

```
public function index(){
    $bike1 = Bike::get()->first();
    $bike2 = Bike::get()->skip(1)->first();
    return view('compare.index')->with(['bike1'=> $bike1, 'bike2'=> $bike2 ]);
}
```

Here I have passed only the first and second row to the blade view.

Blade view:

```
Select first bike
<form action ="{{ route('compare.get', [$bike1->id, $bike2->id])  }}" method="get">
    <div class="first_bike" style="width:200px;">
        <select name="bike1">
            <option value="{{ $bike1->id }}"> {{ $bike1->name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    Select second bike
    <div class="second_bike" style="width:200px;">
        <select name="bike2">
            <option value="{{ $bike2->id }}"> {{ $bike2->name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button type="submit"> Compare </button> 
</form>
```

The get controller passes the value to another view that displays the data. It works.

How can I pass all the rows to the blade view? I know I can use all functions and loop the variable in the blade to get all the rows. Like this

```
@foreach($bike1 as $b1)
<option value="{{ $b1->id }}"> {{ $b1->name }}</option>
@endforeach

@foreach($bike2 as $b2)
<option value="{{ $b2->id }}"> {{ $b2->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

If I do this, then how can I use the `$b1` and `$b2` as route parameters in the action properties in the form?
Can I manipulate the solution from the controller leaving my blade as it is? Or how do I change the blade view in order to achieve my goal? I am stuck

Comment: Your question is not cleared

Comment: which part was not clear ? @sta

Answer (score 0):

well if I am getting you correctly your Controller should be like

```
public function index(){
$bike1 = Bike::all();
$bike2 = Bike::all();
return view('compare.index')->with(['bike1'=> $bike1, 'bike2'=> $bike2 ]);
```

}

Then you modify your view to

```
Select first bike
<form action ="{{ route('compare.get'}}" method="get">
    <div class="first_bike" style="width:200px;">
        <select name="bike1">
            @foreach($bike1 as $b1)
            <option value="{{ $b1->id }}"> {{ $b1->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    Select second bike
    <div class="second_bike" style="width:200px;">
        <select name="bike2">
            @foreach($bike2 as $b2)
           <option value="{{ $b2->id }}"> {{ $b2->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button type="submit"> Compare </button> 
</form>
```

For submitting you don't have to put them as route parameters,, just let the form submit and get the GET variables in the Controller that you are submitting the form to,,You can use the Request object to do this

```
$bike1 = Request->input('bike1');
$bike2 = Request->input('bike2');
```

hope you understand this,, just make sure the Request object is set as a parameter in the controller that you are submitting to